# Microsoft SQL Server Function - Working in peculiar way

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have requirement for searching particular string and replace all the occurrence with specified string, but SQL Server engine is not returning the expected result.

Example

```
SELECT REPLACE(  'NO 49 HEATHERD RD RD 560011'
                ,' RD '
                ,' Road ')
```

I am expecting the return value to be `'NO 49 HEATHERD Road Road 560011'`

But I am getting `NO 49 HEATHERD Road RD 560011`

Note- There can be more than to occurrence of the RD. Let me know if anyone faced the same issue.

Comment: It's because you have white space before and after the values you are finding/replacing. Remove the trailing space and it should get your desired result

Comment: @Dohsan trailing spaces are ignored by sql server (as per SQL standard), the leading space needs to be removed (or even better; both).

Comment: Hi, if we remove the space then it will replace all the unintended characters, which is not right. Is there any other alternative other than removing the trailing space. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Interesting. Your expected output should be correct but I suspect that during the replace of the first " RD " instance the replacement is doing something causing the space to, well, not be there..... If you add an additional space between the 2nd and 3rd "RD" values in the main string, or if you remove the trailing space from " RD" it works as expected. Cool question, I've learned something useful :)

Comment: @HoneyBadger At the end of the final string it would be, but a trailing space can be used in the string_pattern parameter. SELECT REPLACE('1 1 1 1 1 1 ','1 ','1')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

already one space RD one space [NO 49 HEATHERD RD ]replace by word road. In next letter there is no space in front side only [RD 560011] left. So as per your word [ RD ] only replace

Comment: Nice answer and makes sense. The space technically no longer exists because it was the last character replaced, so the next instance of RD is "RD " without the leading space. This makes sense because something like SELECT REPLACE(  'abcabcabc'
,'bc'
,'bcbcbc') would just loop forever otherwise.

Comment: Thanks you, that sounds logical :) . One more question :), do you have alternative idea to handle these scenarios.

Comment: @SanjayJanardhan. As per your given expected output, It can be driven from below query SELECT REPLACE(  'NO 49 HEATHERD RD RD 560011',' RD',' Road')